# How to set PFObject as singleton

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, singleton

I'm trying create a singleton that I can access throughout my app from an object that I've saved in the Member class. It's essentially all the profile details about an object that are saved and managed outside of the Users object.

Here's my code for the singleton, but the return within init is happening before I can actually get a response from Parse, so the data for currentMember is not set, and my NSLogs are not firing.

Is there a way to make the return wait for the return from Parse?

```
#import "MyMember.h"


@implementation MyMember

@synthesize currentMember;

#pragma mark Singleton Methods

+ (id)sharedMember {
    static MyMember *sharedMyMember = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyMember = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyMember;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Members"];
        [query whereKey:@"memberUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
        [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *member, NSError *error) {
            if (member) {
                currentMember = member;
                NSLog(@"My Member %@",member);
            } else{
                NSLog(@"No Member");
            }
        }];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    // Should never be called, but just here for clarity really.
}

@end
```

Comment: quick glance, but this phrase `the return is occuring before I can actually get a response from Parse, so the data for currentMember is not set before it returns and I don't actually get an object in my usage.` ... this sounds confusing. Pleas examine it

Comment: Updated with a little clearer description and simpler code.

Comment: You could make the query synchronous by changing it a `getFirstObject` just to see if that fixes the problem. I do not recommend leaving it there, as blocking the main thread is very bad.

Comment: 1. Initially you can create an empty object and reference it all over the place without any async code.

2. You can persist this object on disk and restore it (maybe using object pinning) when your app loads.

3. This is how PFUser.currentUser works I guess.